# How to do like this style in Google Map

Tags: google-maps

↓ click to show image
[[show googlemap_style_screenshot_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYpwf.png)]

how to do this style in google map?
this style is not custom marker. (all of poi)
I deleted my browser's cookies and then returned to the default style.
It happened by chance. But I can not try again.
thank you for reading.

Comment: sorry. i'm new user. so my reputation is few to image post :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [new interface](https://www.blog.google/products/maps/google-maps-gets-new-look/) of the Google Maps webapp.

Not all of what is provided in the Google Maps webapp is provided when using Google Maps API. So at the moment, there is no solution that can easily replicate this look. But you can style maps on your own. Read more about it here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

There's even a styling wizard: https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/